# MVC : Not render css class for certain view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to css and don't have much knowledge about it.

I have  a mvc application which uses a theme that is built based on bootstrap.

And in my _layout view I have this code

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("_alerts")
    @RenderBody()       
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -myApp</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that all  my view will be wrapped by `container body-content` class.

Which is fine, because my web app's content is not displayed in full width stretched.

But my home page(landing page) let's say. Has a slider and because of the `container body-content` class it is not being shown in full width.

This is how my home page starts

```
<div class="fullwidthbanner-container" style="overflow:visible">
    <div class="fullwidthbanner">
        <ul>
            <!-- Slide 1 -->
            <li data-transition="slideright">
   ...
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

and here is the class for `fullwidthbanner-container`

```
.fullwidthbanner-container {
    width: 100%!important;
    max-height: 550px!important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    margin:0px 0 0px;
}
```

How do I make my home page be not wrapped around`container body-content`?

Please let me know if I have to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

In your `_Layout.cshtml` add a code block before your HTML:

```
@{
     string classToSet = "";
     string action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as String;
     string controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as String;

     //you might need to check for nulls 
     if (!(action == "Index" && controller == "Home"))
     {
         classToSet = "container body-content";
     }
}
```

You can then set the class using Razor:

```
<div class="@classToSet">
     @Html.Partial("_alerts")
     @RenderBody()       
     <hr />
    <footer>
         <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -myApp</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: you always have solution to my problems. And pretty awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the place you put the @RenderBody() and re-structure the layout page

for example you can do this

```
<body>
@RenderBody()

<div class="container body-content">
    @Html.Partial("_alerts")      
    <hr />
</div>

<footer>
    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -myApp</p>
</footer>
</body>
```

By doing so you you view will not affect by the div with class container, body-content

Comment: But this will affect all the views and not just single view

Comment: you should construct you layout in a more general way for layout view, if you need to have different layout simple using @layout ="url" so that you can render specific layout for certain view, if you want to change layout based on controller or others things you can set your logic in _ViewStart.cshtml